# Intellij idea code completion for React

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, completion

I have a `spring boot` application and now I try to implement SPA using `reactJS`. But code completion doesn`t work in my IDE.

[image]

My version of Intellij Idea: ultimate 2017.1

I try to add react library in `Preferences|Languages&Frameworks|JavaScript|Libraries` but I could not find `react` in this list.

[image]

I try to add types with `npm install @types/react --save`
but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

If you have same problem try to update idea. In my case it helped